# Why are my params not showing up in the url?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Why are my action and params not showing up in my url?  I am using the zend 2 framework.  I have a search action and a results action.  Below is my search action (not using variables as I test):

```
        return $this->forward()->dispatch('Application\Controller\Index', array(
        'action'     => 'results',
        'zip'   => '12345',
      ));
```

The route is a child of my home route.

```
            'results' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'results[/:zip]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'results',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Below is the parent route

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'constraints' => array(
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
```

I am getting routed to the correct view but the url returns www.foo.com as opposed to www.foo.com/results/12345.

In addition how can I stop the post request on a forward?  There is a form on the results page and after the forward this form is again submitted (causing a loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the browser to display the new URL then you need to perform a HTTP redirect as the forward plugin will dispatch to the new controller in the *same* request.

Replace the forward call with a call to the redirect plugin.

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/results/route/name');
```

This will also solve your addition issue where the HTTP method is still set as POST (as the redirect will be a `GET` request).

Comment: How do I pass the variables using this method?                  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/results',array(
                    'zip'=>$homeSearch->zip,

Comment: return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/results',array(
                    'zip'=>$homeSearch->search_zip,

Comment: Alex,  How do I prevent the controller from looking back at the previous action?  I have a condensed search and full search. I redirect from the condesed to the main but it looks as if it is going back to the main one each time as opposed to looping inside itself.

Comment: @Matt It would be difficult to answer without seeing the code for both controller actions; it might be easier if you ask another another question with it in.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  If you get a chance I have posted a new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152910/how-do-i-pass-variables-to-another-action-from-a-search-form