# Blank Parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Following up on my previous question

[Why are my params not showing up in the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130773/why-are-my-params-not-showing-up-in-the-url)

What is the best way to deal with blank parameters?  Do I need to write an if statement for each field and assign a value if null?  Currently I have 2 parameters and if the first one is blank it is setting the value of the second parameter as the first
Below is an example.  If Zip is the first parameter and bar is the second...

```
www.foo.com/results/12345/bar
zip = 12345
bar = bar
```

if the first param is empty...

```
www.foo.com/results/bar/
zip = bar
```

I would like to do this in the url so the below won't work.

`$search_zip = $this->params()->fromRoute('zip','default');`

Below is where I post the params.

```
       return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/results',array(
            'zip'=>$homeSearch->search_zip ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create a route

```
'results' => [
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route' => 'results[/:zip][/:bar][/]',
            'defaults' => [
                '__NAMESPACE__' => '...',
                'controller' => '...',
                'action' => '...',
                'zip' => 'default',
                'bar' => 'default'
            ],
            'constraints' => [
                'zip' => '[0-9]+',
                'bar' => '[a-z]+'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

in controller

```
$this->params('zip');
$this->params('bar');

$this->redirect()->toRoute('results', ['zip' => 123, 'bar' => 'bar']);
```