# How do I pass variables to another action from a search form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have two search pages. One is a condensed search form the other is an advanced search.

I would like the user to enter their search at on the condensed page and be redirected to the results page which contains the advanced search fields.

The two issues I currently have are:

- How do I redirect?
- What is the best practice for when a field is left blank?

Currently, I keep looking back to the index to get the first two search fields

**Condensed Search**

```
public function indexAction()
{
     $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
     $form = new HomeSearchForm($dbAdapter);        
     $request = $this->getRequest();   
     if ($request->isPost()) {    
         $homeSearch = new HomeSearch();          
         $form->setInputFilter($homeSearch->getInputFilter());                
         $form->setData($request->getPost());            
         if ($form->isValid()) { 
             $homeSearch->exchangeArray($form->getData());

             if($homeSearch->search_zip == null)
             {
              $homeSearch->search_zip = 'null';
             }

             if($homeSearch->industry_name == null)
             {
              $homeSearch->industry_name = 'null';
             }


           return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/results',array(
                'zip'=>$homeSearch->search_zip ,
                'industry'=>$homeSearch->industry_name,
           ));

         }
          else {
              echo "Error";
          }           
    }
      return array('form' => $form);
}
```

**Results/Advanced Search**

```
public function resultsAction()
{        
     $search_zip      = $this->params()->fromPost('zip');
     $search_industry = $this->params()->fromRoute('industry');
     $search_language      = $this->params()->fromPost('language');
     $search_gender      = $this->params()->fromRoute('gender');
     $search_name      = $this->params()->fromRoute('name');

     echo var_dump($search_zip);
      echo var_dump($search_industry);
      echo var_dump($search_gender);
     echo var_dump($search_name);

     $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'); 
     $proSearch = new SearchQuery($dbAdapter);
     $form = new SearchForm($dbAdapter); 

     $request = $this->getRequest();   
     if ($request->isPost()) {
         echo 'i post';
         $search = new MainSearch();          
         $form->setInputFilter($search->getInputFilter());                
         $form->setData($request->getPost());  

         if ($form->isValid()) { 
             $search->exchangeArray($form->getData());
             if($search->search_zip == null)
             {
              $search->search_zip = 'null';
             }

             if($search->industry_name == null)
             {
              $search->industry_name = 'null';
             }

             if($search->language_name == null)
             {
              $search->language_name = 'null';
             }

             if($search->pro_gender == null)
             {
              $search->pro_gender = 'null';
             }


         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/results', array(
            'action'     => 'results',
            'zip'   => $search->search_zip,
            'industry'   => $search->industry_name,
            'language'   => $search->language_name,
            'gender'   => $search->pro_gender,
            'name'   => $search->pro_name,
          )); 

         }  
     }

      return array(
          'form' => $form,
          'pros' => $proSearch->proSearch($search_zip,$search_industry,$search_language,$search_gender,,$search_name),
              );
}
```

**Update**

I am able to get the search to work with the method I have posted below.  However I still cannot get the parameters to post in the url (I am able to get the url I want using this code however I have trouble applying the filter and binding the fields to the form  `$this->form->setAttributes(array('method' => 'GET'));`

Isn't the Post Redirect plugin used to prevent users from going back?  After reading the manual I am not sure how I go about using this plugin?  I'm not sure why the segment is not setting with the below code, I have used this in the past.

```
'search_zip'=> $this->search_zip
```

**ModuleConfig**

```
            'results' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'results[/:search_zip][/:search_industry][/:language][/:gender][/:designation][/:name]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'results',
```

**ResultsAction**

```
  public function resultsAction()
    {   
         $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'); 
         $proSearch = new SearchQuery($dbAdapter);
         $request = $this->getRequest();   
         $form = new SearchForm($dbAdapter);  
         if ($request->isPost()) {
             $search = new MainSearch();          
             $form->setInputFilter($search->getInputFilter());                
             $form->setData($request->getPost());  
             if ($form->isValid()) { 
                 $search->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                 $search_zip = $search->search_zip;
                 $search_industry = $search->search_industry;
                 $search_language = $search->search_language;
                 $search_gender = $search->search_gender;
                 $search_designation = $search->search_designation;
                 $search_name = $search->search_name;
             }  
         }

          return array(
              'form' => $form,
              'pros' => $proSearch->proSearch($search_zip,$search_industry,$search_language,$search_gender,$search_designation,$search_name),
                  );

    }
```

**ResultsView**

```
//Search Index

 $title = 'Search';
 $this->headTitle($title);
 ?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
 <?php
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
     'home/results',
     array(
         'action' => 'results',
         'search_zip'=> $this->search_zip

     )
 ));
 //$form->setAttributes(array('method' => 'GET'));
 $form->prepare();

 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('industry_name'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('search_zip'));
 echo '<br>';
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('language_name'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('pro_gender'));
 echo '<br>';
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('designation_name'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('pro_name'));
 echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));

 ?>
 <h2>Results</h2>
 <table class="table">
 <tr>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>Street Address</th>
     <th>Office Number</th>
     <th>City</th>
     <th>State</th>
     <th>Zip</th>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
 </tr>
 <?php foreach ($pros as $pro) : ?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($pro->pro_first);?></td>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($pro->pro_last);?></td>
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($pro->pro_street_address);?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($pro->pro_office_number);?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($pro->pro_city);?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($pro->pro_state);?></td> 
     <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($pro->pro_zip);?></td> 
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I wouldn't redirect ...

In your search view phtml you can simple do:

```
<?php $this->form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('your/results/route'))->prepare();?>
```

and you can then remove all the code from index that handles the post. I wouldn't use two form classes just use one and only render the items you need on the page!

```
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('search_zip'));
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('industry_name'));
    echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

If a user doesn't enter anything in a field just leave it blank

**** UPDATE *****

If you do want to use the segment routing then you could make those sections optional in your routing

```
'options'   => array(
                'route'    => '[/:language]',
 )
```

Kind of hard to show you without seeing your routing but that should work.

see http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment

Comment: I would like to show the search terms in the URL which I why I defaulted to 'null'.  If I let the field remain null it shifted the url parameters to and the route I defined would be off.

Comment: I don't really think you should be using segment routes to store form data personally, as much as I dislike Get Param Query Strings, I would be using them if I needed to do that kind of thing

Comment: How would you approach the situation?  I would like to post the search terms in the url to provide a 'unique' url based on the search (it seems like this is common practice?)  I am new to the zend framework and it looked like the feature that was used has since been deprecated (http://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2013-01)

Comment: I'd either use segment routing and optional parameters and set like you are doing in controller or do $this->form->setAttributes(array('method' => 'GET')); and then use good old fashioned query string params with some server side validation.

Comment: I have the below code in my view but it wont pick up the variables.  If I hard key something in I can see it in the url however. $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
     'home/results',
     array(
         'search_zip' => $this->search_zip,
         'industry' => $this->industry_name,
     )
 ));

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored the code you provided to display how I would approach the issue.

Study the approach carefully; the key changes are **encapsulating** the functionality.

**Prerequisites**

- Both forms should `POST` to the `resultsAction()`
- You only need one 'type' of search object (called `Search` here)
- Encapsulate! Both forms provide results and search, it will make your code considerably easier (to read and maintain) if you logically separate the functionality

Not tested, that's your job!

```
public function simpleSearchAction()
{
    $form = $this->getSimpleSearchForm();

    return new ViewModel(compact('form'));
}

public function advancedSearchAction()
{
    $form = $this->getAdvancedSearch();

    return new ViewModel(compact('form'));
}

public function resultsAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form = $this->getAdvancedSearch();
    $results = array();

    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $search = new Search();
            $search->exchangeArray($form->getData());

            // Execute the search and return the results
            $results = $this->search($search);

            // Populate the form with the search data
            $form->bind($search);
        }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form'    => $form,
        'results' => $results,
    ));
}

protected function search(Search $search)
{
    // do search here, although this shouldn't be
    // in the controller, rather a service!
    return $yourResults;
}

// This should be injected into the controller
protected function getAdapter();

// Forms should be using the FormElementManager, not
// being created using new
protected function getSimpleSearchForm();

// Same as above
protected function getAdvancedSearch();
```

**To Think about**

- Post Redirect plugin (if you want nice URL's with the search terms)
- Dependency injection! Your missing out on the benefits of ZF2, create the `DbAdapter` and `Forms` in service factories and *inject* them into the controller's constructor.
- Service layer - Moving out the `search` code will make it reusable and separate the *controller* logic from *business* logic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a detailed response.  I've updated my code based on your suggestions (still working on grasping dependency injection).  Currently my search is residing in a different file with my other queries (it works when I manually pass the variables).  I'm still having trouble getting my form to post in the url.  Below code is not passing into url (it will if I hard code values).  However it does seem to be passing to the action as the form is binding with the new values.

Comment: $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
     'home/results',
     array(
         'search_zip' => $this->search_zip,
         'industry' => $this->industry_name,
     )
 ));